# Grub rescue on USB

Tags: usb, grubrescue, windows-10

I made the mistake to install Ubuntu on my USB. After some time I wanted to use it normally again (also the OS was really slow) so I formatted it. The problem is, I burned a Windows 10 ISO to it and tried to boot from it but I get the following message: "Unknown filesystem: grub rescue>" , meaning Ubuntu was not completely removed with the format.How do I format the USB correctly so that this message doesn't display?

Comment: It sounds more like GRUB is installed on the computer itself, not the USB drive.

Answer (score 0):

To completely wipe the drive, I would create a new partition table.

If you can use Ubuntu, follow these steps to create a new partition table:

1. **Install `gparted`.** GParted is a great graphical partition management tool. You can install it from a terminal using: `sudo apt-get install gparted`, or by searching for it in the Ubunutu Software Center.
2. Open gparted by searching for it in the dash or from a terminal with the command `gparted`. You will be prompted for your password.
3. **Select the correct drive.** Open the dropdown (usually it reads `/dev/sda`), and select the drive you want to format. Verify that you are working with the correct drive by looking at its capacity. Be careful!
4. **Generate a new partition table.** Once you are sure you have selected the right drive, select `Device`, and then `Create partition table...` (this might not be exact, as for me it is written in a different language). Then you will be prompted to select the type of partition table you want to create. Generally, I would use `gpt`, but for USB-drives `msdos` is also fine. Note that `msdos` only supports a maximum of 4 partitions and that `gpt` only works on 64-bit computers.
5. **Create a new partition.** If you want to create a partition now, right-click on the empty space, and select new. Configure its size and type (FAT32 should do in your case) and press Add.

This procedure can also be completed in Windows.